# Elastic search model gem (rails), add new field to mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Following is the API to update mapping of Elastic search

```
PUT twitter/_mapping/tweet 
{
 "properties": {
   "user_name": {
    "type": "string"
   }
  }
 }
```

This add a new field called user_name to the tweet mapping type.
How to achieve this using elastic search model gem
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the put_mapping API for this purpose.

For your case, the following should work.

```
client = Elasticsearch::Model.client

data = { "tweet" => { "properties" => { "user_name" => { "type" => "string" } } } }

client.indices.put_mapping(
{
 index: 'twitter',
 type: 'tweet',
 body: data 
})
```

Comment: Note that type "string" is no longer used as of 6.0; specify "text" or "keyword" instead https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings